# Amazon RDS + Spring MVC + Flyway - Getting no database selected

Tags: java, mysql, spring, amazon-rds, flyway

I'm trying to integrate Amazon RDS with webapp developed in Spring MVC. I'm using Flyway as db migration tool. I'm able to connect to the RDS but the thing is whenever flyway starts the migration, it tries to create `schema_version` table without firing `use database_name` query.
And that's where RDS throws error saying `"No Database Selected"`.

I tried setting schema for flyway, `flyway.setSchemas("koomi");`, but no help, its still giving same error.

So is there any way by which we can make flyway to execute `use database_name` query before it fires query for `schema_version`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the database name in the url and you should be ok

Comment: Dude, I've used `flyway.setDataSource(dataSource);`, and have set url for datasource.

Comment: Ohh wait, I'm getting what you trying to say, s**t man how do I missed that? My bad.

Comment: Thanks Man, I always put db name in url, but somehow I missed to put it this time, my bad. BTW great work by developing flyway, thanks a lot for saving our time. Great Work. :)